# What is a "Scalar" Query?

Tags: sql, database, executescalar, llblgen

I am using LLBLGEN where there is a method to execute a query as a `scalar query`. Googling gives me a definition for `scalar sub-query`, are they the same ?

Comment: My guess, repeat guess, is that it is a query that returns one row with one record.  Something like select count(*) from etc.

Answer (score 51, accepted):

A scalar query is a query that returns one row consisting of one column.

Answer (score 10):

For what it's worth:

> Scalar subqueries or scalar queries are queries that return exactly
> one column and one or zero records.

[Source](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=jfKoCwAAQBAJ&pg=PA155&lpg=PA155&dq=Scalar+subqueries+or+scalar+queries+are+queries+that+return+exactly+one+column+and+one+or+zero+records.+They&source=bl&ots=n0N4nni0PO&sig=9Tjb7P3Yu0Th3K4X1gAuJCqE_Q4&hl=ro&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwia3ba1vL7UAhVJJMAKHQaPCrIQ6AEIJzAA#v=onepage&q=together.%20Scalar%20subqueries%20or%20scalar%20queries%20are%20queries%20that%20return%20exactly%20one%20column%20and%20one%20or%20zero%20records.&f=false)

Answer (score 8):

A scalar method is used for aggregate functions such as max, min, sum, avg and so on. Whenever you want to return a single value after execute the query.