# How to combine two query's results into one row?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two queries that return one result each i.e one number

```
Select Count(*) as StockCountA from Table_A where dept='AAA'
```

Results

```
StockCountA 
550
```

.

```
Select Count(*) as StockCountB from Table_B where dept='BBB'
```

Results

```
StockCountB 
450
```

I wish to join the two results into one row record i.e

```
| StockCountA | StockCountB    
| 550         | 450
```

Answer (score 58, accepted):

You can use:

```
select
(Select Count(*) as StockCountA from Table_A where dept='AAA') as StockCountA,
(Select Count(*) as StockCountB from Table_B where dept='BBB') as StockCountB
```

Explanation: you can select single value as a field in a select statement, so you could write something like

```
select
  x.*,
  (select Value from Table_Y y) as ValueFromY
from
  Table_X x
```

This will work only with [*scalar* queries](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44556182/511529), meaning that the sub-query should have exactly 1 column, and at most 1 row. With 0 rows ValueFromY will return `NULL` and with more than 1 row, the query will fail.

An additional feature of `select` (in SQL Server, MySQL and probably others) is that you can select just values without specifying a table at all, like this:

```
Select
  3.14 as MoreOrLessPI
```

You can combine both those facts to combine the two counts into a single result, by writing a query that looks like:

```
Select
  (Select query that returns at most 1 row) as Result1,
  (Select another query that returns at most 1 row) as Result2
```

Comment: Thanks if you know the basics then you know what your doing otherwise your are an expert :)

Comment: Yeah, that's why I decided to add a bit of explanation after all. It's hard to find the right documentation I you don't know what to look for. :)

Answer (score 7):

This should give you the desired result:

```
SELECT * FROM(
(Select Count(*) as StockCountA from Table_A where dept='AAA') StockCountA ,
(Select Count(*) as StockCountB from Table_B where dept='BBB') StockCountB
);
```

Comment: Interesting variation on the other answers. You are basically using the old (pre 1992) join syntax to cross join the two queries. The result will be the same, though.

Answer (score 0):

While not always the best practice, it is possible to do a CROSS JOIN..

```
SELECT
COUNT(Table_A.SOME_COLUMN) as StockCountA
,COUNT(Table_B.SOME_COLUMN) as StockCountB
FROM Table_A, Table_B WHERE Table_A.dept='AAA' AND Table_B.dept='BBB'
```

Answer (score -1):

Try below SQL :

```
select (Select Count(*) as StockCountA from Table_A where dept='AAA')  StockCountA, 
       (Select Count(*) as StockCountB from Table_B where dept='BBB')  StockCountB
```

Hope This Helps :)